# When to use UITouch vs UIScroll

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to achieve the design you see in dating apps. Where you can vertically scroll images of a profile and also horizontally scroll to view the next or previous person in the list.

Currently I have my views laid out as such.

```
Previous-UIView  -      current UIView -    next UIView 
    UIScrollView.           UIScrollView.       UIScrollView
        Images.                 Images.             Images
    UIView.                 UIView.             UIView
        Profile info.           Profile info.       Profile info
    UIPageControl.          UIPageControl       UIPageControl.
```

Only one of the Views occupies the main view with next and previous off screen. Ideally when the user moves the view left I would programmatically remove the previous view, make current the previous, the next current and add a new view for next. Visa versa for moving right.

What is the best way to scroll the views horizontally?

Should I wrap them all in a UIScrollView? And would that interfere with the UIScrollView sub Views?

Or should I program touch controls to move the views?

Or is there a better way?

I'm still a newbie at iOS development so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A page-based scroll view might be helpful. http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift

Comment: This tutorial is great, thanks. I guess the big question is can you have Scrollviews inside Scrollviews?

Comment: I recommend you avoid nesting scroll views and that includes nesting things built with scroll views like table views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've tried some experimenting with a test app and I'm pleased to say you can have UIScrollviews inside UIScrollviews.

I was able to get it running perfectly. Here is my code below.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.superView.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var subImages1 = ["IMG_0004.JPG","IMG_0005.JPG","IMG_0008.JPG"]
    var subImages2 = ["IMG_0009.JPG","IMG_0010.JPG","IMG_0011.JPG"]
    var subImages3 = ["IMG_0013.JPG","IMG_0017.JPG","IMG_0018.JPG"]
    self.images.append(subImages1)
    self.images.append(subImages2)
    self.images.append(subImages3)
    self.superView.frame = self.view.frame
    self.superView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width*3, self.view.frame.height)
    self.superView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:self.view.frame.width,y:0)
    self.superView.pagingEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(self.superView)


    //layout the UIVeiws into the master ScrollView
    for i in 0...2{
        var offset = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        var pView = UIView()
        pView.frame = CGRectMake(offset, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        pView.backgroundColor = colours[i]
        self.superView.addSubview(pView)
        self.profileViews.append(pView)

    }

    // Add sub Scroll views and images to the Views.
    for (index, view) in enumerate(self.profileViews){
        var scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.frame.width-20, self.view.frame.height-20)
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.frame.height * CGFloat(images[index].count))
        for (index2, image) in enumerate(images[index]){
            var subImage = UIImageView()
            subImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.frame.height * CGFloat(index2), scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.frame.height)
            subImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            subImage.image = UIImage(named: image as! String)
            scrollView.addSubview(subImage)
        }
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.scrollViews.append(scrollView)


    }
}

//Use the did end decelerating as it executes the code once the scoll has finished moving.
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if(scrollView == self.superView){
        var contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        var pageWidth = self.superView.frame.width
        var fractionalPage:Double = Double(self.superView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth)
        var page = lround(fractionalPage)


        // In this example I take the last UIView from the stack and move it to the first.
        // I would do the same in the real app but update the contents of the view after
        if(page == 0){
            var tempView = self.profileViews[2]
            self.profileViews[2].removeFromSuperview()
            self.profileViews.removeAtIndex(2)
            for view in self.profileViews{

                view.frame  = CGRectMake(view.frame.minX + self.view.frame.width, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
                println(view.frame)
            }
            tempView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tempView.frame.width, tempView.frame.height)
            self.profileViews.insert(tempView, atIndex: 0)
            self.superView.addSubview(tempView)
            var newOffset = contentOffset.x + pageWidth

            self.superView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: newOffset, y: 0)

        }
        // Take the first view and move it to the last.
        if(page == 2){
            var tempView = self.profileViews[0]
            self.profileViews[0].removeFromSuperview()
            self.profileViews.removeAtIndex(0)
            for view in self.profileViews{

                view.frame  = CGRectMake(view.frame.minX - self.view.frame.width, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
                println(view.frame)
            }
            tempView.frame = CGRectMake(tempView.frame.width*2, 0, tempView.frame.width, tempView.frame.height)
            self.profileViews.append(tempView)
            self.superView.addSubview(tempView)
            var newOffset = contentOffset.x - pageWidth

            self.superView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: newOffset, y: 0)

        }

    }
}
```